# Set 'Modify All' for around 100 profiles

Tags: administration, profile, metadata, configuration

I want to give 'Modify All' permission for certain objects, to around 90-100 profiles in my org (excepting a few). I feel it is very laborious work.. 
Is there a way to do this easily through the IDE-way? through some metadata manipulation?

Comment: This might be similar issue with you. [http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14126/how-to-give-an-access-on-an-object-to-all-the-profiles-which-are-in-system]

Answer (score 9):

Why not use list views to do this?

1. create a list view on Profiles, filtering on the profiles you want
   to modify
2. add only the columns 'Modify all' for the objects you
   want to assign (by searching on 'object permissions'
3. save the list view
4. tick the 'select all' checkbox at the top-left of the
   list view
5. check the 'modify all' checkbox on one of the records.
   The system will ask you if you want to apply the change on all
   selected profiles.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure the above suggested way would help a lot but if you are planning to pursue with the IDE WAY then --
For all the Objects which do not have modify all will have metadata as below: [image: Profile Metadata object permissions]

So in order to give the profile read all and modify all permissions you will have to manually change it to below format. You can also use find and replace to edit the metadata of multiple profiles at the same time.